# How do I convert a column of month (January, April) in character format to date format?

Tags: r, date, as.date

I have tried using as.Date to convert a column of months in the format January, February into data format rather than character. It has failed multiple times, please help.

```
cause_of_death <- cause_of_death %>% 
  mutate(month = as.Date(month, "%B"))
```

Output:

```
month   n
april   3
may     4
february 7
```

Comment: I *guess* that this is about R, but since I don't really use it much I can't be sure. If it's wrong, please re-tag with the correct language.

Comment: In what calendar is `february` the 7th or 8th month?

Comment: Yes its R, sorry for not mentioning that

Answer (score 0):

`as.Date` needs a *whole date*, including year, month, and day-of-month. Since you don't have all of those, you would need to either add them, convert to `Date`, and extract the month number from that, or just:

```r
library(dplyr)
cause_of_death %>%
  mutate(n2 = match(month, tolower(month.name)))
#      month n n2
# 1    april 3  4
# 2      may 4  5
# 3 february 7  2
```

FYI, base R has two variables baked in:

```r
month.name
#  [1] "January"   "February"  "March"     "April"     "May"       "June"      "July"      "August"    "September" "October"   "November"  "December" 
month.abb
#  [1] "Jan" "Feb" "Mar" "Apr" "May" "Jun" "Jul" "Aug" "Sep" "Oct" "Nov" "Dec"
```

Comment: I see now. Thank you very much for providing answers to my question